# Vue router in laravel project not working on root folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js, router

I am using vue router with my laravel project when I run that inside a folder it works fine example it works fine in localhost/demo/admin#/dashboard but it doesn't work when I run it on root folder as localhost/admin#/dashboard.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code of Vue router and the blade view

Comment: what "doesn't work"? do you happen to have an `admin` folder in your `public` folder?

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The scaffolding does not work by default in laravel 6, but it's quite easy to get it configured and running.

Install the scaffolding by running:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

And than run

```
php artisan ui vue
```

That will generate the scaffolding. You should be all set now.

check https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend for more

As an extra point, if you create components, you will need to define it in `resources/js/app.js` like so:

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prioritizing these routers may cause disruption of the routing that is related to the vue router.